# Covariance between sum of iid random variables and sum of indicator functions

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, covariance

The question is-

> Let $X_1,X_2,..,X_n$ be iid random variables from a continuous distribution whose density is symmetric about $0$. Suppose $\mathbb{E}(|X_1|)=2$ and define $Y=\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$ and $Z=\sum_{i=1}^{n}I(X_i>0)$. Then calculate covariance between $Y$ and $Z$.

My attempt:

$E(X_i)=0$ for all $i=1(1)n$ because $X$ is symmetric about $0$ and $E(|X|) $ exists.

Now,

$Cov (Y,Z)=E(YZ)-E(Y)E(Z)$
$=E(YZ)-0$
$=E[(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i)(\sum_{i=1}^{n}I(X_i>0)]$

$=(\sum_{i=1}^{n}E[(X_i.I(X_i>0))]$ $+\sum\sum_{i \neq j}E(X_i)E(I(X_j>0)$ as $X_i,X_j$ are independent.

$=\sum_{i=1}^{n}E[(X_i.I(X_i>0)] +0 $ as $E(X_i)=0$

$ =\sum_{i=1}^{n}\{E[X_i.I(X_i>0)|I(X_i>0)=1]×1/2] + E[X_i.I(X_i>0)|I(X_i>0)=0]×1/2]\}$

$=\sum_{i=1}^{n}E[X_i.I(X_i>0)|I(X_i>0)=1]×1/2] +0$

$=\sum_{i=1}^{n}E[X_i|X_i>0]×1/2]$

$=2n×(1/2)$
$=n$

Is my reasoning correct ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note: you use independence the line *before* what you state, when you already "separate" the expectations in the second sum.

Comment: @ClementC. Yeah,gonna edit it. But is the method correct?

Comment: I am not convinced the last lines are correct, no. The way you handle the conditional expectation to relate it to the expectation of the abssolute value.

Comment: @ClementC. I used the formula $E(X)=E(X|A)P(A) +E(X)=E(X|A^c)P(A^c)$

Comment: Yes, but how do you derive $\mathbb{E}[ X_i I(X_i > 0) | X_i > 0 ] = \mathbb{E}[|X|]$? That's the part missing.

Comment: @ClementC. I have included the missing steps in my edit.please see

Comment: I... can't see where? Why is $E[X_i|X_i > 0] = E[|X|]$?

Comment: @ClementC. I thoght like this- the conditional distribution of $X|X>0$ woyld be **twice** the distribution of $X$ and so the expectation becomes $2. \int_{0}^{\infty} f_X(x)dx=2.1=2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a missing part at the end: you didn't show how you get

> $\mathbb{E}[ X_i I(X_i > 0) | X_i > 0 ] = \mathbb{E}[|X|]$
>   which is something you rely on at the very end.

---

*Below is an argument avoiding conditional expectations altogether.*

Assume $X$ is continuous (in particular, no mass at $0$) and symmetric around 0. You have
$$
\mathbb{E}[X \cdot I(X>0)]
= \mathbb{E}[|X| \cdot I(X>0)]
= \mathbb{E}[|X|  - |X|\cdot I(X<0)]
= \mathbb{E}[|X|]  - \mathbb{E}[|X|\cdot I(X<0)] \tag{1}
$$
but, by symmetry of $X$ around 0, $X$ and $-X$ have same distribution, and so $$\mathbb{E}[|X|\cdot I(X<0)] = \mathbb{E}[|-X|\cdot I[-X<0]]  = \mathbb{E}[|X|\cdot I(X>0)]\tag{2}$$
so that, from (1),
$$
\mathbb{E}[X \cdot I(X>0)] = \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}[|X|]
$$
allowing you to conclude from what you wrote at the beginning (the first 3 equations).

Comment: So actual answer would be $n/4$?

Comment: I don't get how the eqality happens in 1.

Comment: @user587126 which of the equalities?

Comment: The equation you numbered as 1

Comment: @user587126 Yes, there are several equalities in there.
The first should be clear: $X\cdot I(X>0)=|X|\cdot I(X>0)$. The second is from $|X| =|X|\cdot (I(X>0)+I(X=0)+I(X<0))==|X|\cdot (I(X>0)+I(X<0))$  (as $X$ is continuous, $I(X=0)$ is 0 a.s.). The last one is from the previous, using linearity of expectation.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that part. I understand what you are saying. But, if i calculate $E(X.I(X>0)|X>0)=E(X.1|X>0)$ like this- the pdf of $X|X>0$ is $f_X(x)/P(X>0)= 2.f_X(x)$ , right?. So the required expectation is nothing but : $2. \int_{0}^{\infty} f_X(x)dx=2.1=2$ which does not matches with your answer which is $2/2=1$. I don't know what I am missing here. Please help.

Comment: @user587126 (from my phone) I don't understand how you compute the expectation. Aren't you, for a start, missing an $x$ in the integral? This is an expectation, not just the integral of the pdf...

Comment: Sorry,that was a typo. I meant $xf_X(x)$ and i am getting the integral's value by using E(|X|)=2 which means $\int_{-\infty}^{0} (-x).f_X(x)dx+\int_{0}^{\infty} (+x)f_X(x)dx=2$ which gives us $2.\int_{0}^{\infty} x.f_X(x)dx=2$,where i substituted $x=-(y)$ at the 2nd integral.

Comment: @user587126 You have a mistake somewhere, I can't look where exactly whether if in your density or somewhere in your derivation with conditional expectation. A sign your expectation is wrong: by definition, $$E[X I(X>0)] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty xI(x>0) \cdot f_X(x)dx = \int_0^\infty x f_X(x)dx$$ while you seem to claim it's twice that.

Comment: But i am calculating the expectation you said **given the condition that** $I(X>0)=1$, i.e, **$X>0$**, that's why a $2$ is being multiplied

Comment: But you *added* that condition. The original goal is to compute what I wrote. Somehow, you added conditional expectations in the middle, and in the end did not get the right answer (if I'm reading correctly what you are saying). So it looks like you got it wrong in the "middle part". @user587126

Comment: But i am just using the formula of $E(X)= E(X|A).P(A)+ E(X|A^c).P(A^c)$

Comment: I would suggest you write your whole derivation, step by step, somewhere, and check it step by step, instead of shattering it across comments. You claim your derivation yields
$$
\mathbb{E}[ X I(X>0) ] =\mathbb{E}[ |X| ] 
$$
However, this conclusion is wrong (if you cannot see why, check with an example, e.g., standard Gaussian). Hence, a step is wrong. @user587126

Comment: God knows what is wrong with me. Thanks anyway for your answer.

Comment: @user587126 Sorry I cannot help further with checking where exactly your mistake was (I am not in front of my laptop right now). In general, I'd suggest avoiding conditional expectations whenever you can -- using them is much trickier than other techniques.,,

Answer (score 1):

You have correctly shown that

\begin{align}
\mathbb{Cov}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i,\sum_{j=1}^n I(X_j>0)\right)&=\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n\mathbb{Cov}(X_i,I(X_j>0))
\\&=\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{Cov}(X_i,I(X_i>0))+\sum_{i\ne j}^n \underbrace{\mathbb{Cov}(X_i,I(X_j>0))}_{0}
\\&=\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}(X_1I(X_1>0))
\end{align}

Now just use these equations which follow from the law of total expectation: $$\mathbb{E}(X_1)=\mathbb{E}(X_1 I(X_1>0))+\mathbb{E}(X_1 I(X_1<0))$$

and $$\mathbb{E}(|X_1|)=\mathbb{E}(X_1 I(X_1>0))+\mathbb{E}(-X_1 I(X_1<0))$$

The above can be written using conditional expectations of course but there is no need for that.

Comment: Thanks. But what is wrong in my method. But, if i calculate $E(X.I(X>0)|X>0)=E(X.1|X>0)$ like this- the pdf of $X|X>0$ is $f_X(x)/P(X>0)= 2.f_X(x)$ , right?. So the required expectation is nothing but : $2. \int_{0}^{\infty} x.f_X(x)dx=2.1=2$ which does not matches with your answer which is $2/2=1$. I don't know what I am missing here. Please help.

Comment: I don't see where it leads to if you condition on these events. This is completely unnecessary. Keep in mind that $E(X_1 \mid X_1>0)=\frac{1}{P(X_1>0)}E(X_1 I(X_1>0))$.